# What is the right site for my question regarding a request for suggestions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I developed an app in MS access which can be used by a small business for preparing quotation & invoice. Currently, the access file is stored in dropbox which is the backup.

I utilized the feature in MS Access where you can develop forms. So, all the user has to do is just enter the product and price. The you have a professional looking quotation in a pdf file.

I now want to develop this application so it can be accessed from a browser. Developing an application from scratch and hosting it somewhere is my last resort.

Which is the right place for me to ask this question? I have got too many "off-topic" or "subjective" and I am honestly clueless what to do about it.

Comment: you can develop your `Web Application` using `Microsoft ASP.net` it gives great connectivity with your `.access` file. 
`Stackoverflow` is a community where you can ask your queries/problems which you are facing while development.

Comment: In general, asking for suggestions or opinions is off-topic broadly across the network, because they don't lend themselves to our Q&A format: they almost universally devolve into popularity contests. The exceptions are the "X Recommendations" sites, like Software Recommendations, but even there there are some pretty stringent constraints on what can be asked. If you're not looking for a tool so much as a tutorial, then you're really out of luck. SE is more like a dictionary, a random-access recede work,  than a tutorial or other time-ordered guide.

Answer (score 4):

> I have got too many "off-topic" or "subjective" and I am honestly clueless what to do about it.

And this seems to be just one other like that too. You need to be very specific in order to make it answerable at all.

If you are looking for conversion software, Software Recommendations might be the place to ask, but we can't tell that from your question. On that site they need very specific information in order to give you any advice.

If you have a specific coding problem in the conversion process, Stack Overflow is the place, but your question doesn't look like it would even fit in its current form.

If you are looking for advice 'Where should I start?', generally, there is no site where you could ask that. It is too broad, too subjective.

Comment: Honestly, I do not understand why subjective answers are not encouraged. I do understand that some people just take it very personal and get abusive. But I believe that its in the light of very persons experience that they develop opinions and expressing which becomes "subjective".
With the huge crowd of people here, I feel its their opinions that help newbies like me to have an open mind and develop.

Comment: @qbektrix The various merits and demerits of subjective questions have been discussed ad-nauseum on this site and the various child metas. If you really do trust the opinions, and therefore decisions, of the huge crowd of experts here, then trust in turn that the right decisions were made in the prohibition of subjective questions. SE is not and does not intend to be the end-all-be-all of technical help on the internet. If you want a tutorial on web development, there are thousands, a full course by an established university, hundreds, best practices, reams. Supplement SE with other sources.